# Why does this code snippet print 10 infinitely in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does the following C++ code snippet keep printing 10 indefinitely?

```
int num = 10;
while (num >= 1)
   cout << num << " ";
   num--;
```

Comment: The only statement in the while loop is `cout << num << " "`, `num--` is NOT in the scope of the loop. Add curly braces `{ }` to enclose it.

Comment: Compilers will typically warn about this if you enable warnings https://godbolt.org/z/fY6T6voqa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your snippet is the equivalent of this when using braces:

```
int num = 10;
while (num >= 1)
{
   cout << num << " ";
}
num--;
```

Meaning only the printing statement is part of the loop.  What you want is this:

```
int num = 10;
while (num >= 1)
{
   cout << num << " ";
   num--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a while loop in c ++ you will have to enclose the inner code between `{}`, like this:

```cpp
while(/* Condition */){
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be familiar with python, though in c++ scoping ain't linked to indentation.

With correct indentation, it would look the following:

```
int num = 10;
while (num >= 1)
   cout << num << " ";
num--;
```

I would really recommend a formatting tool like clang-format here, as it would immediately gave you this feedback.

Scopes in C++ are done using {}.
As such, the code should be:

```
int num = 10;
while (num >= 1)
{
   cout << num << " ";
   num--;
}
```

If you don't specify the {}, only the next statement is part of the scope.

In this case, I guess you are trying to learn while loops. Though this code is better fit for a for-loop.

```
int num = 10;
for (int num = 10; num >= 1; num--)
   cout << num << " ";
```